# Fill in "secret word" letters

Tags: java, string, replace

I am doing a hangman project.
I have got most of the code working.

The one part I can't get working is where the "secret word" has more than one letter which is the same. For example "hello" has 2 "l"'s.

This is the code for the part of the code where it replaces the "----" (hello) with the letter that was guessed if the guess was right:

```
int pos = $Input.indexOf($Guessed); 

if (pos == -1) 
{ 
    System.out.print("Search string '" + $Guessed + "' not found"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    System.out.println("\nSearch string found at " + (pos + 1));              
    pos = $Input.indexOf($Guessed);
    String before = $Display.substring(0, pos); 
    String after = $Display.substring(pos + $Guessed.length()); 
    System.out.println(before + $Guessed + after); 

    $Display = before + $Guessed + after;
    System.out.println($Display);            
    $GuessAmt++;
}
```

I have looked at various answers on here but I cannot get one to work so far.
Obviously if someone guessed "l" then "-----" would change to "--ll-" for (hello).

I am not looking for someone to code this for me as I enjoy a challenge but a bit of a hint would be lovely!!

Obviously from looking at my code you may be able to guess we are not allowed to use arrays yet unfortunately. This is only an intro to Java class really.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just to be clear, at the moment it ONLY does the first "l" not both the "l"'s of (hello).

EDIT: Changed to this. However, now it is repeating the "inside if" print statement over and over. Cant see how to fix this!

```
int pos = $Input.indexOf($Guessed); 

        if (pos == -1) 
        { 
            System.out.print("Search string '" + $Guessed + "' not found"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            //System.out.println("\nSearch string found at " + (pos + 1)); 

            for(int i=0;i<$StrLength;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                if($Input.charAt(i) == $Guessed.charAt(0))
                {
                    i = $Input.indexOf($Guessed);
                    String before = $Display.substring(0, i); 
                    String after = $Display.substring(i + 1); 
                    System.out.println("inside if" + before + $Guessed + after); 
                    $Display = before + $Guessed + after;
                }
            }



                System.out.println($Display);



            $GuessAmt++;
        }
```

Comment: Please do not use dollar signs in identifiers.  Those should be reserved for identifiers generated by the compiler (or maybe by other automatic code generation tools).

Comment: Yes, you should never use dollar signs in your identifiers.  And you should observe standard capitalization conventions -- start function and variable names with a lower-case character, start classes with an upper-case character.

Comment: You told it you only want to do this replacement once.  The compiler is not a mind reader.  If you want to do this more than once, you need a loop.

Comment: @ajb - i have tried multiple loops from multiple related questions on here but to no avail. I didnt want to post a loop which may be completely wrong as that would divert the post from the intended question. Thanks for the advice regarding dollar signs

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Use a loop, the "trick" is to pass the *offset* (previous pos) to `indexOf` (used to determine pos) so that the loop will advance.

Comment: Could you explain that a little further please? The offset part

Comment: @Dr.Pepper See the [`String.indexOf(char,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) overload.

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Alternatively, you could iterate the string manually all the way through (and not use indexOf at all), which might arguably be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Didnt expect answers this quick. Was planning to sleep and put some fresh eyes on it tomorrow, been working on this for about 3 hours now! Will go through the responses tomorrow and report back. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still wanna use the `indexOf` you can use its overloaded version as well to insure that you have gone through all letter occurrences:

```
int index = str.indexOf('l');
while(index  >= 0) {
     // FILL THE BLANKS WITH THE LETTER
     index  = str.indexOf('l', index +1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `String` and check every character individually using `word.charAt(i)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == guessedChar) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: hi mate, added something similar to what you suggested but cant get it to work. See edit above in OP